# How do I get time spent on a Task, excluding Holiday and Non-working hours?

Tags: apex, tasks, businesshours

How do I get time spend on a Task, excluding Holiday and Non-working hours?

I'd like to get the total time spent on a Task, excluding holidays and non working hours.

Is there a feasible way and how it can be achieved in Salesforce?

Comment: Is that task is related to cases?

Comment: no, it is not related to Case

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup Organization Business Hours, please have a look at:

setup-> company profile-> business hours

Also, you can manage the holidays under :

setup-> company profile-> Holidays

May be a little bit of customization for calculation on Task start and end date, in comparison to the above should do the job.